How to enter cursor as an input in procedure oracle
I want to create a procedure that uses cursor as an input in Oracle. I tried something like this:
cursor cur is select * from table t1;

and then also:
create or replace procedure (I want to input cursor cur here)
is
begin
end;/

How can I do that?

Hi - what do you think the datatype of the parameter you’re passing into the SP would be? Why not just run the cursor within the SP - that seems a much easier approach?

If you need to pass a cursor, you must use a REF CURSOR. Use the sys_refcursor type for an easily available weak ref cursor, open it for the query desired, and pass it to the procedure which should be expecting an argument of type sys_refcursor. It can then fetch from the cursor, but it is it's responsibility to ensure it fetches into the correctly aligned row structure. It aids immensely to standardize a column list for cursors being passed to a particular proc. Do be aware that using ref cursors is an intermediate technique, not something that should be used unnecessarily.

@NickW I cannot use the table in the procedure as the table exists in different database and i don't have privileges to create database link and don't have access to create the table or a procedure in a different databases

@Mark - If there is no database link and you cannot create a database link, I cannot see how you would open a cursor that queries from the remote table in the database where the procedure exists in order to pass the sys_refcursor to the procedure.  You can't connect to the remote database, open a cursor there, and then pass that to the local procedure if that is what you are thinking of.  You'd have to address the underlying problem that you want data from a remote database but the local DBA does not want connections to that remote database.

Here's an example which shows one way to do it.
Procedure that accepts cursor as a parameter, loops through it and displays it contents:
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test (par_cursor in sys_refcursor)
  2  is
  3    l_ename emp.ename%type;
  4    l_sal   emp.sal%type;
  5  begin
  6    loop
  7      fetch par_cursor into l_ename, l_sal;
  8      exit when par_cursor%notfound;
  9      dbms_output.put_line(l_ename ||' - '|| l_sal);
 10    end loop;
 11  end;
 12  /

Procedure created.

How to use it?
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_rc sys_refcursor;
  3  begin
  4    open l_rc for
  5      select ename, sal
  6        from emp
  7        where deptno = 10;
  8    p_test (l_rc);
  9  end;
 10  /
CLARK - 2450
KING - 5000
MILLER - 1300

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>

